# Ajax.BeginForm OnFailure return empty result when connecting via HTTPS

Tags: model-view-controller, ajax.beginform

When connecting via a non-secured protocol (http), my MVC 5 web application returns the error message properly. But the moment I connect via https, the error message is blank. Thought? NOTE: I try json return also.  Thanks!

Browser debugger output

HTTP

[image]

HTTPS

[image]

```
MVC Controller:
string message = string.Join(" ", errors);
Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.RequestedRangeNotSatisfiable;
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(Response.StatusCode, string.Join(" ", message));

Script:
function ajaxOnFailure(response, status, error) {
debugger;
if (response.status == 500) {
    error = "An internal error has occurred. Please try again. If the problem persists, please contact IT."
}
toastr.error("", error);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a workaround. Instead of return a fail response, I return OK response and determine the type of message via jquery. It would have been nice if a fail response return the message via https.

[image]

[image]